# My google map link only works once

Tags: jquery, arrays

I have just inserted a link into my site which appends a lightbox to the screen with googlemap locations.

it works but when you close it, and click it again it does not load the second time, what am I doing wrong?

```
$(function(){
                var googleMap = $('<iframe height="600px" width="800px" scrolling="no" src="googlemap.html">');
                var lightbox = $('<div class="lightbox"><span class="close">X</span></div>');
                var overlay = $('<div class="overlay"></div>');

                $('.map-link').click(function(){
                    if ($(window).width() < 499) {    
                        console.log();
                    } else {
                        $('.wrapper').append(overlay);
                        $('.wrapper').append(lightbox);
                        $(lightbox).append(googleMap);      

                        $('.lightbox span').click(function(){
                            $(overlay).fadeOut();
                            $(lightbox).hide();
                        });
                    }
                });//end of click
        }); //end
```

I have not decided what to do with it for mobile yet, so ignore the console log.

Comment: Try `$(lightbox).html(googleMap);` instead of append. Most likely the multiple appended instances of the map are causing the issue. If that works you will need to add another div to the lightbox where you can add the map to so that the close button doesn't get removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never did anything with googlemaps, but I don't get why you are embedding a file named "googlemap.html"? I did a little research and found this site:
https://developers.google.com/maps/tutorials/fundamentals/adding-a-google-map
On this site they use a completely different approach. Maybe take a look at it?